# Asp.net Web API not calling correct method

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm calling the default Account/ResetPassword api but it doesn't get hit. Some other method does and I can't figure out which one. Is there a way to step through the process so I can see which method is being called?

Here's the default method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("api/Account/ResetPassword")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
```

I'm using PostMan to test the call.
By the way, this used to work. It seems to have stopped working after a number of other methods were added but we're not sure exactly when.

**Update**

I found which method was being called. In order to prevent it, I added a Route attribute to it. Now I'm getting the following messages.

```
{
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:55914/api/Account/ResetPassword'.",
"MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Account' that matches the request."
}
```

**Update 2**

I was able to resolve the issue by removing the route from the ResetPassword. I have no idea why this would work. I didn't move the ResetPassword from the default Account controller.

Comment: Did you have a controller level attribute?  [Route("api/[controller]")] if so having a route attribute as you've set it up would cause that issue.

Comment: @Rav that was the issue! Thanks.

Comment: jbassking10 upvote? thanks